# Show image when clicking image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, click

I am making a fake computer screen with images. I have a picture of a Firefox icon and when the mouse hovers over it, it increases in size, and I would like another picture to appear when clicking on the picture of the icon. This is the closest I have been able to get.

```
<html>
<title> Scope </title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>

<embed src="73797^alarmclock.mp3"; autostart="true"; loop="true"; hidden="true";/>

  <body>
         <img src ="alarm clock2.jpg"/>

     <p>  Pulling the sheets into my body, I begin to sink back into the bed... 
          uggh... my alarm clock... time to get up..

         <img id="computerscreen" src= "computer.jpg"/>

         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="script.js"></script>

         <img  id="grow" src="icon2.gif"/> 

         <img class="show hidden" src="screen2.jpg" />



</body>
```

Here is CSS

```
#grow{
    position:absolute; 
    top:1157px; 
    left:599px; 
    width:47px; 
    z-index:4; 
    height:47px;
}

#grow:hover{
    top:1137px; 
    left:589px;
    width: 70px; !important;
    height: 70px; !important;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
    position:absolute; 
    top:300px; 
    right: 0px; 
    width:850px;
    height:550px;
    z-index:6;
}

#computerscreen{
    position:absolute; 
    top:300px; 
    right: 0px; 
    z-index:3;
}
```

and Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#grow').click(function() {
        $('.hidden').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: If your callback function is empty, you don't need to include it.

Comment: what's the "slow", function(){}); for? If you don't need to do anything after the fadein, then you don't need the function(){}.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't need the callback from the `fadeIn()`, just call `fadeIn`

```
$('.hidden').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

on '.hidden' in the css remove the display:none; and hide it in the jQuery so here is what the jQuery will look like...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hidden').hide();

    $('#grow').click(function () {
        $('.hidden').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

I have also removed the callback function, because you do not need it.

Comment: My .hidden image automatically loads on the page still even with the .hide function.. any thoughts why?

Comment: it may sounds silly, but 2 things 
1) Try ending the paragraph tag with </p>
2) Delete the cache
also, have you checked the console log to make sure there are no errors?

Comment: what browser are you using to test?

Comment: I just checked the console log. It said, "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:1
Failed to load resource

Comment: That's why then... the jquery api isn't loading properly so none of it will work... <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

put that in the head of your file and remove the one you put in that's just above your import of script.js

Comment: My console log now tells me                                     Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:1
GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js  website.html:6
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mp3: "file:///C:/Users/RockyRoad/Desktop/Austin/73797%5Ealarmclock.mp3".
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mp3: "file:///C:/Users/RockyRoad/Desktop/Austin/73797%5Ealarmclock.mp3".

Comment: can you remove all that embed stuff out of your file? also you haven't done any of the standard stuff, like open and close head tags, you haven't closed the html tag either

Comment: I removed the embed mp3, added head tags and the closing html just didn't show on my post, and I am still getting the jscript refference error                                                  GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js  website.html:8
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: on your import of the jquery api you need to add http: as a prefix if you're working from localhost... so it will look like this... <script type='text/javascript' src="http:// ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> ... just without the space in the link

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad to be of assistance, would you be able to take the time to mark my answer as the correct answer?

Comment: If you don't mind, the next thing I am trying to add is another jquery to have the image disappear when clicking on the image again, yet I can't figure it out. Care to help?

Comment: sure, you basically just need an if statement with in jquery...  $('#grow').click(function () {
 if($('.hidden').is(':hidden')) {
  $('.hidden').fadeIn('slow');
 } else {
  $('.hidden').fadeOut('slow');
 }
});    

basically, it will check if the item is hidden, if it is it will fade it in, if not then fade it out

Comment: well you will have a few errors with that bacause that's not how you create a variable in jquery, that's how to create a variable in php... the solution I have you on my previous comment should just work

Comment: I am baffled because my image automatically appears now even though the first code I have in the script is the hide() function

Comment: then this is where you check the console to find out if any more errors are popping up

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input script.js:4

Comment: copy and paste your whole jquery file?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $('#grow').click(function () { 
    if($('.hidden').is(':hidden')) { 
    $('.hidden').fadeIn('slow'); 
    } else { 
    $('.hidden').fadeOut('slow'); } });

Comment: try this... $(document).ready(function () { 
 $('.hidden').hide(); 

 $('#grow').click(function () { 
  if($('.hidden').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.hidden').fadeIn('slow'); 
  } else { 
   $('.hidden').fadeOut('slow'); 
  } 
 });
}); ... you missed the end brace